# Kafka Connect - How will developers develop against Kafka connect?

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect

We are infrastructure team who's want to maintain the Kafka cluster . In that case , we are planning to provision Kafka environment for developers. My questions here , How can I provision Kafka connector to developers for them development activities .

Comment: Just point them to the [Connect Developer Guide](https://docs.confluent.io/current/connect/devguide.html) and share the version of your Kafka cluster.

Comment: If you're providing brokers, then you don't need to provide Connect workers. Developers can always test using `connect-standalone`